# Compose mutableState from viewmodel

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have 2 Mutable States in my `ViewModel` and want them to observe the textfields in my composable.

`ViewModel`:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AddEditTransactionViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val moneyManagerUseCases: MoneyManagerUseCases
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _transactionDescription = mutableStateOf("")
    val transactionDescription: State<String> = _transactionDescription

    private val _transactionAmount = mutableStateOf("")
    val transactionAmount: State<String> = _transactionAmount
```

`Composable`:

```
@Composable
fun AddEditTransactionScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: AddEditTransactionViewModel = hiltViewModel(),

    ) {

    // This works
    var descriptionState by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var amountState by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    // This doesn't work
    var viewModelDescriptionState = viewModel.transactionDescription.value
    var viewModelAmountState = viewModel.transactionAmount.value

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = viewModelDescriptionState,
            onValueChange = { viewModelDescriptionState = it },
            label = { Text(text = "Description") })
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp))
        TextField(
            value = viewModelAmountState,
            onValueChange = { viewModelAmountState = it },
            label = { Text(text = "Amount") },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
        )
```

It works if I use the state from my composable but that kind of beats the purpose of the ViewModel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line:

```
var descriptionState by remember { mutableStateOf(") }
```

It works because you're updating the value of `mutableState` via delegation. It's easier to understand if you look at how you would do same without delegation:

```
val descriptionState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
//...
descriptionState.value = "new value"
```

`remember` will save same object between recompositions, but this object have `value` field which is changing.

On the other hand, here:

```
var viewModelDescriptionState = viewModel.transactionDescription.value
```

you create a local variable, and any changes will not be saved between recompositions.

This is usually solved by creating a setter function within the view model. You can also use delegation in the view model, if you want to restrict it to update without a setter, you can add `private set`, instead of having `private _variable` and `public variable`:

```
var transactionDescription by mutableStateOf("")
    private set

fun updateTransactionDescription(newValue: String) {
    transactionDescription = newValue
}
```

This is considered best practice because the setter can contain more logic than a simple update value. In the case where you only need to store it, you can remove the `private` part and update it directly, without the setter function.

You can find more information about the state in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) Compose, including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

`AddEditTransactionScreen`:

```
@Composable
fun AddEditTransactionScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: AddEditTransactionViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val descriptionState = viewModel.transactionDescription
    val amountState = viewModel.transactionAmount

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = descriptionState.value,
            onValueChange = { viewModel.updateTransactionDescription(it) },
            label = { Text(text = "Description") })
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp))
        TextField(
            value = amountState.value,
            onValueChange = { viewModel.updateTransactionAmount(it) },
            label = { Text(text = "Amount") },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
        )
    }
}
```

`AddEditTransactionViewModel`:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AddEditTransactionViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    private val _transactionDescription = mutableStateOf("")
    val transactionDescription: State<String> = _transactionDescription

    private val _transactionAmount = mutableStateOf("")
    val transactionAmount: State<String> = _transactionAmount

    fun updateTransactionDescription(value: String) {
        _transactionDescription.value = value
    }

    fun updateTransactionAmount(value: String) {
        _transactionAmount.value = value
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

Its `transactionDescription` and `transactionAmount` attributes are of the `State<String>` type, the `State` type cannot have its value changed, unlike the `MutableState` type, a simple solution that maintains the change protection only by the view model, is creating a method for each attribute that you want to change and make this change in the attribute that is `MutableState`.